# The equation $e^{x^3-x} - 2 = 0$ has solutions...

Tags: exponential-function

The equation $$e^{x^3-x}-2$$

1. has no solution in $[0,1]$
2. has a unique solution in $[0,1]$
3. has two solutions in $[0,1]$
4. has four solutions in $[0,1]$

Correct answer is B but how do you approach a problem like this? Can you post a solution please? What does $[0,1]$ even mean?

Thank you

(thanks for the edit)

Comment: I assumed you meant $e^{x^3}-x-2$. If you instead meant $e^{x^3-x}-2$ or $e^{x^3-x-2}$, please change it to the correct one by clicking the "edit" link on the bottom of your post.

Comment: its all good thank you :)

Comment: Also "in [0,1]" means "between $0$ and $1$ (including $0$ and $1$)".

Comment: Fix your title please

Comment: noooow that makes sense haha thanks, I see why its 2.

Comment: Then I think you should answer your question yourself.

Comment: @XcoderX [Your edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2610174/5) overwrote and undid [OP's previous edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2610174/4) (and then the title and the body of the question no longer matched). This is why I rolled back your edit. Let the OP decide what they *really* meant to ask.

Comment: @DeniKatsman $x^3-x=x(x^2-1) \le 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$, so $e^{x^3-x} \le e^0 = 1 \lt 2$, which would mean that the correct answer is **1.**. Maybe you should doublecheck that you asked the right question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have asked " What does $[0, 1]$ mean?"

It means all $x$  real numbers  $x$ such that $ 0\le x\le 1$

In order to solve $$e^{x^3-x} =2 $$ We take logarithms to get $$ {x^3-x} = \ln2$$

We are looking for solutions in the closed interval $ [0,1].$

Note that for $ x\in [0, 1]$

$$ {x^3-x} \le 0$$ and $\ln(2) =0.6931...$ is positive.

Thus there is no solution between $0$ and $1$.
The option $1$ is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{x^3-x}=2=e^{ln 2}$

⇒ $x^3-x=ln 2$

$x ≈ 1.245$

Hence this equation has no solution in $[0, 1].$

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get the answer is to note that $x^{3}-x\leq 0$ and hence $e^{x^{3}-x} \leq 1 <2$.